# Cannot correctly select <option> in Polymer Dart

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I am trying to select an `<option>` in a `<select>`, but no matter what I do, the first `<option>` is always selected. Here is the code:

```dart
<select value="{{item.theme}}">
  <option template repeat="{{theme in allThemes}}"
      selected?="{{theme == initialSelectValue}}">
    {{theme}}
  </option>
</select>
```

This happens even if `{{theme == initialSelectValue}}` returns `true`. Further, looking at the markup generated, the correct `<option>` has the `selected` attribute correctly applied, yet it is not selected.

Anyone know what is wrong? And is there an alternate way (perhaps using `selectedIndex`) that I can use instead?

Using Polymer version 0.10.1+1.

Comment: I'm wondering if `<select value="{{item.theme}}">` is a problem. If I remove the `value` attribute, the checked status displays fine (but of course the `<select>` stops being functional).

Comment: Do you have an initial value assigned to `item.theme`? I saw a bug yesterday where it led to problems when the field has a default value.

Comment: And that is exactly the problem. Do you want to officially answer the question, so I can then accept it, Günter?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you run into this bug

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19467

A default value for an `@observable` field causes problems.